# How can I put a bound on an associated type of a generic method's trait bound in a trait with its own associated type?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to figure out why the following won't compile. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eb6f4c795880d3a12d7304bb22a49cfe))

```
pub trait Foo {
    type FooType;

    fn foo<E>(x: Self::FooType) -> E
    where
        E: TryFrom<Self::FooType>,
        E::Error: std::fmt::Display;
}

struct MyFoo;

impl Foo for MyFoo {
    type FooType = MyFooType;

    fn foo<E>(x: Self::FooType) -> E
    where
        E: TryFrom<Self::FooType>,
        E::Error: std::fmt::Display,
    {
        match x.try_into() {
            Ok(y) => y,
            Err(err) => panic!("Failed"),
        }
    }
}

struct MyFooType;
struct MyOtherType;

impl TryFrom<MyFooType> for MyOtherType {
    type Error = String;

    fn try_from(value: MyFooType) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        Ok(MyOtherType)
    }
}
```

The error the compiler gives me is as follows.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `E: From<MyFooType>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:15:5
   |
15 | /     fn foo<E>(x: Self::FooType) -> E
16 | |     where
17 | |         E: TryFrom<Self::FooType>,
18 | |         E::Error: std::fmt::Display,
   | |____________________________________^ the trait `From<MyFooType>` is not implemented for `E`
   |
   = note: required for `MyFooType` to implement `Into<E>`
   = note: required for `E` to implement `TryFrom<MyFooType>`
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
17 |         E: TryFrom<Self::FooType> + std::convert::From<MyFooType>,
   |                                   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: the trait bound `E: From<MyFooType>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:15:8
   |
15 |     fn foo<E>(x: Self::FooType) -> E
   |        ^^^ the trait `From<MyFooType>` is not implemented for `E`
   |
   = note: required for `MyFooType` to implement `Into<E>`
   = note: required for `E` to implement `TryFrom<MyFooType>`
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
17 |         E: TryFrom<Self::FooType> + std::convert::From<MyFooType>,
   |                                   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

The compiler seems to complain that `E` does not implement `TryFrom<Self::FooType>`, but that is precisely what the trait bound should enforce.

What surprises me is that if I remove the `E::Error: std::fmt::Display` bound, it compiles just fine.

Comment: Just so you know, it's generally better to use `TryInto` as a trait bound rather than `TryFrom`, and similarly `Into` rather than `From`.  [The docs explain why](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html).

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me. Minimal reproduction: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8211078d8184d6e365b2bc790b716390.

Comment: And thanks @ChayimFriedman for this example. It illustrates the problem much better. I hope you don't mind I used your example in the GH issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/116377

Comment: Of course not. Opening an issue is the right thing to do.